# How to run 2 or more input files in the same form with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to know how to run 2 or more input files in the same form, I have to upload some documents by using php, I made separate forms and they work, but I need to all together however I dont know how. I need to put only two forms as example actually I need to put 3 but the 3rd is larger so it would be much code to read with an example putting only two I would be able to do the rest.

Note: Form 1 and Form to upload data to different tables.

Form 1

```
 <div class="container">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn'])){
    $fileName=$_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $fileTmpName=$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
   
    $fileExtension=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $allowedType = array('csv');
    if(!in_array($fileExtension,$allowedType)){?>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            INVALID FILE
        </div>
    <?php }else{
        $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
        $k = 0;
        $energies = array ();
        while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE) {
          $k++;
          if ( $k > 1 ) {
                $energies[] = $myData[3];
             }
            }

            list($e1, $e2, $e3) = $energies;
            $query = "INSERT INTO metlab.resultados_impacto_junta (energy1, energy2, energy3) VALUES ($e1, $e2, $e3)";

            $run = mysql_query($query);

        if(!$run){
            die("error in uploading file".mysql_error());
        }else{ ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    SUCCESS
                </div>
    <?php   }
    }
}
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3 class="text-center">
        RESULTS
    </h3></hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="myFile" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name ="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Form 2

```
<div class="container">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn'])){
    $fileName=$_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $fileTmpName=$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
    //RUTA DEL ARCHIVO
    $fileExtension=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //FORMATOS DE ARCHIVO PERMITIDOS
    $allowedType = array('csv');
    if(!in_array($fileExtension,$allowedType)){?>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            INVALID FILE
        </div>
    <?php }else{

        $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
        $k = 0;
        while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,','))!== FALSE){
         $k++;
          if ( $k > 4 ) {

               
                $valor_dureza = $myData[3];
                
                

                $query = "INSERT INTO metlab.resultados_tension_junta (size,yield,tensile,ra,elongacion)
                VALUES ('".$valor_dureza."')";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
             }

        }
        if(!$run){
            die("error in uploading file".mysql_error());
        }else{ ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    SUCCESS
                </div>
    <?php   }
    }
}
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3 class="text-center">
        RESULTS
    </h3></hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="myFile" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name ="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like a form like this:
[image: example]

With the Fk I would know which number the 3 docs belong to.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? both forms on the same page? Or one big form?

Comment: I updated the post with an image of how I would like the new form I hope that helps

Comment: Yeah I can't understand either. Your image you provided doesn't match up with your code at all. Where is the RESULTS title, and I can't see three file uploads in your code. Why are there two forms, when you've only shown one in the image? Your question isn't very clear, sorry. Unless I'm being thick, what's the problem with having three file upload elements within one `<form>` tag?

Comment: The image provided is the form I would like to make. But I cant
There are two forms because the only way I can upload the documents I need is by doing separate forms

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: Please be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection. Also, share what you've tried to resolve the problem. Is this problem ("run 2 or more input files in the same form") really related to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself I just changed the vars of the forms and thats all, Its a dirty and bad solution but it works for now.